# Godox X1R-c connectivity

Tags: canon, godox

In the past I was using my Canon 430EXII and Godox AD200 with Godox X2T-C Trigger and it was working fine.
Recently, my trigger broke and needed to buy a new one. Now I have Godox XProC, unfortunately, I could not get it peered with Godox X1R-C.
I watched different Youtube videos, searched online, read the manuals but could not find what I am doing wrong.
The transmitter and the receiver is both set to same channel and groups. Does anyone have any suggestion, what I may be doing wrong.
By the way AD-200 fires fine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about the ID number? All of [these similar questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=Godox%20ID%20number) turn out to be about the ID number.

Comment: If the ID number setting does not resolve your issue, please let us know and include more information about your camera settings, transmitter settings, receiver settings, and flash settings and we'll reopen the question with your updates edited into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When we have similar questions here, it's almost always the same thing.

I'm going out on a limb here and assume you have the transmitter properly attached to the camera's hot shoe with on-camera flash enabled in the camera's menu. As far as the camera is concerned, the XPro-C *is* the flash.

I'm also going to assume you have the 430EX II properly attached to the Godex receiver with the flash *not* set to slave mode. As far as the flash is concerned, the X1R-C *is* the camera.

We'll also assume both the XPro-C and X1R-C are both set to the same channel and group.

*What else could it be?*

In addition to *Group* and *Channel*, the newer Godox/Flashpoint transmitters and receivers (both internal and external) have the ability to designate an **ID number** of 1-99 (plus "Off"). The older pieces of the system do not have the ability to use ID numbers. In order to use the older pieces with the newer ones, the ID number setting needs to be "Off" on the newer units. Even with the newer units, the ID numbers that are set on each unit must match each other or the other unit will ignore it.

If your X1R-C uses firmware version 18 made since January 10, 2018 then the following instructions allow you to set the "RF ID" on the X1R-C:

> The customer can set RF ID. Operation: press the CH and GR button simultaneously and power it on to enter the RF ID setting interface. Short or long press the CH button to add the ID value while short or long press the GR button to decrease. Power off the flash trigger after 5s, and ID value can be set and saved. Then, power it on, and the ID value will affect RF reception.

To check what firmware version your X1R-C is running hold down the group button [GR] while turning the X1R-C on. The firmware version will be displayed as long as you hold down the [GR] button. When you release the [GR] button the firmware version will no longer be displayed and the channel and group number will be displayed.

There's a micro-USB port under the rubber flap on the left side of the X1R-C that will allow you to attach it to a computer to update the firmware using the [Godox G1 Firmware updater software](http://en.godox.com.cn/Downloads_s_Firmware.html).